# wrong name error when runing HelloServer in CORBA/JAVA tutorial

Tags: java, corba, idl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

I've gone through all of the steps from the corba/java tutorial (here is the link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/GShome.htmll)  but when I run the server with this command :

```
 start java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost
```

this error is displayed in another prompt :
[image: here it is]

do you have any idea to resolve this problem,

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you copy/paste that error ? Referencing an image on another site is a little fragile and unsearchable

Comment: This error happens when the JVM tries to load a class, but finds the class file defines a class with the wrong name.  The linked question explains the problem.

Comment: just a classpath problem I beliver , you will have to start like  start java corba1.HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I'll have to go back one directory and run with corba1.HelloServer