# TestRig - Running example from TDA4R Chapter 1

Tags: antlr4

Over the years I have spent a lot of time with ANTLR3 and I was hoping so much to get ANTLR4 working.  I started with the example in chapter 1 of the TDA4R book.  I got to the point of trying to run the TestRig and I got...

```
C:\ANTLR4\tpantlr2-code\code\install>java -cp C:\ANTLR4\antlr-4.0-complete.jar;
org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Hello r -tokens
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloLexer :
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I am running Windows 7 - 64bit, but I presume the jar files are 32bit.  Could this be the problem?  Or is it that I am not on the right version of Java - java version = "1.6.0_24"?

What do I do?  I don't really want to compile the whole system.

Thanks.

Comment: Your version of Java is Too Old.

Answer (score 1):

Use java 1.7.0_13 or newer. If you are using NetBeans with the antlrworks2 plugin, you must use exactly "NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2". If you are seeing other problems, this discussion might be helpful:
[NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)