# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: - wrong name:

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, java-6

Am trying to Run a Java Application, where the Error thrown is

```
5 18:38:06,271 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lucene/search/LuceneSearchModule  (wrong name: com/util/search/LuceneSearchModule)
2013-05-05 18:38:06,271 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Below is my Java Program Code which calls the method -

```
package com.lucene.index;
import com.lucene.search.LuceneSearchModule;
public class LuceneAccess
{ ....
LuceneSearchModule.get(....);
... }

package com.lucene.search;
public class LuceneSearchModule
{ .... }
```

I have placed the LuceneSearchModule class file under com/lucene/search & com/util/search,, but not sure why the error is thrown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name

Answer (score 0):

Why you tried putting the class file in two locations?? Remove the file from com/util/search. And give a try.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Am just working in existing system, the above changes are working fine in development server, but issue appears in production alone

Comment: Then your jar might be missing in the production server. Add the jar manually to the libs folder of your server.

Comment: The required Jar Files, i found in production, becoz the issue exists only in production, i cant able to reproduce in development server

Answer (score 0):

Check the `package` declaration for `LuceneSearchModule` class under `com/lucene/search` folder. If you've copied it from the `com/util/search` location it may still be referring to the `util` directory.