# Class not found when I pass command line arguments

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I have a Java class with a main method that expects arguments. If I run the class without arguments I get an error like this, meaning that Java finds the class, runs it, and generates a runtime ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$ java -cp .:zookeeper-3.4.5.jar org.zookeeper.LsGroup
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.zookeeper.LsGroup.main(LsGroup.java:50)
```

But when I try the same statement with requisite command line arguments, (`zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$ java -cp .:zookeeper-3.4.5.jar org.zookeeper.LsGroup Test`) then I get a class not found error:

```
zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$ java -cp .:zookeeper-3.4.5.jar org.zookeeper.LsGroup Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<clinit>(ZooKeeper.java:94)
    at org.zookeeper.LsGroup.connect(LsGroup.java:19)
    at org.zookeeper.LsGroup.main(LsGroup.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 3 more
zookeeper@zookeeper-virtual-machine:~/zookeeper-3.4.5$
```

I was having a similar problem earlier this morning, but the particular issue on that thread was resolved. 
[Why can't java find my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933918/why-cant-java-find-my-class)

Why do I get a class not found error when I pass command line arguments? How can I fix this?

This is the java code:

```
package org.zookeeper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException;
import org.apache.zookeeper.WatchedEvent;
import org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher;
import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper;
import org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher.Event.KeeperState;

public class LsGroup implements Watcher {

    private static final int SESSION_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private ZooKeeper zk;
    private CountDownLatch connectedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void connect(String hosts) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        zk = new ZooKeeper(hosts, SESSION_TIMEOUT, this);
        connectedSignal.await();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(WatchedEvent event) { // Watcher interface
        if (event.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
            connectedSignal.countDown();
        }
    }

    public void ls(String groupName) throws KeeperException, InterruptedException {
        String path = "/" + groupName;
        try {
            List<String> children = zk.getChildren(path, false);
            for (String child : children) {
                System.out.println(path+"/"+child);
                System.out.println(zk.getChildren(path +"/"+ child, false));
            }
        } catch (KeeperException.NoNodeException e) {
            System.out.printf("Group %s does not exist\n", groupName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        zk.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LsGroup lsGroup = new LsGroup();
        lsGroup.connect(args[0]);
        lsGroup.ls(args[1]);
        lsGroup.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: case of missing dependency, add the slf4j api jar and other dependencies in one single directory and load all the jars in the particular directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like your `ZooKeeper` class has a dependency on `slf4j`. If you don't specify any command line arguments, this line

```
lsGroup.connect(args[0]);
```

will fail with the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that you see. Because of this the `ZooKeeper` class will never be initialized and the depedency to `slf4j` will never be resolved by the JVM.

If you do specify command line argument. The JVM will try to load your class but fail because `slf4j` is not on the classpath. You need to add the relevant jars to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The java classpath is missing the slf4j implementation (I guess is slf4j.jar).

Is this jar bundled into your JAR ?
Or is this JAR somewhere in the classpath?

You need to provide all your class' dependencies in order to run it

Comment: actually it is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Pack all the api jars inside one single directory

use below option on linux env

> java -cp 'PATH_TO_DIR/*' className