# Java Error don't know what it is

Tags: java

I'm doing a small program for school and i'm writing the first part and I run it in NetBeans and everything works fine, but when I submit it for grading I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TextMsgExpander (wrong name: textmsgexpander/Te

being a newbie in Java i'm not quite sure what this means. any guidance would be helpful Thanks in advance

```
package textmsgexpander;

/**
 *
 * @author Craig
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgExpander {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userEntry = "";
        String userOutput = "";

        System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
        userEntry = scnr.nextLine();

       userOutput = "You entered: " + userEntry;
        System.out.println(userOutput);


        return;

        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you submit the code for grading? the classpath may be related, the code may need to be submitted without a package, and using the default package; possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

Comment: We take the .java file and submit it to blackboard where it complies and then tells you if it's correct or not. 
here are the instructions
Instructions
Deliverables
TextMsgExpander.java 
We will expect the above file(s) to be submitted
Compile command
javac TextMsgExpander.java -Werror 
We will use this command to compile your code

Comment: Are there any instructions in the assignment to add the java `class` to a `package`? If no mention of that, try commenting-out (remove) the first line `package textmsgexpander;` and resubmit.

Comment: Here check THIS-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to submit the whole folder or only the .java file?
If the latter, then your problem might be that you define a package, but then submit only the java file.

Try deleting the first line ("package textmsgexpander;") and try again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should change this `userEntry = scnr.nextLine();` to `userEntry = scnr.next();`This should work

Comment: Also check if the package name  `package textmsgexpander;` exist in the src folder. If not, delete that