# NoClassDefFoundError. Runs fine in eclipse, but not from native package

Tags: java, gradle

I have a code that runs fine in Eclipse. But when I try to run through native packaging using Gradle, I get this message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/embraer/rw4j/output/OutputEditorTags (wrong name: com/embraer/rw4j/view/report/OutputEditorTags)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.embraer.rw4j.output.HeaderEditor.handleAddTagContent(HeaderEditor.java:71)
... 86 more
```

The strange thing is that I don't have any package `com/embraer/rw4j/view/report`. I don't know where the JVM is getting this reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

Comment: If you have a Gradle problem, would help if you added the Gradle scripts. Also the command used to reproduce the problem