# How to use both javac and java command in the same directory

Tags: java, javac

I want to compile and execute this program with "javac" and "java" commands :

```
package mypackage;

public class Myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

**The problem I have :** When I am in "mypackage" folder and I use "javac" in it, it produces the file "Myclass.class". But when I use the command "java Myclass" (I'm still in the "mypackage" folder), I have this message :

> Error: Could not find or load main class Myclass
>   Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/Myclass (wrong name: Myclass)

**The solution I found :** I should not go inside "mypackage" folder and execute "java Myclass" but go one folder up and execute "java mypackage.Myclass" (it works).
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509317/10104743

**My question :** I see some people who can run both "javac Myclass.java" and "java Myclass" commands directly without the need to go one folder up as I did. Why does it not work with me and what can I do to fix this ?

Comment: You’ve specified a package name for your class (`mypackage`) so `java` expects to find `Myclass` in a directory called `mypackage`

Comment: You should be in the directory that *contains* `mypackage`, and you should issue `javac mypackage/Myclass.java` and `java mypackage.Myclass`. What you've seen only works if there is no `package` statement.

Comment: If you do not specify a package in your source, then you can use 'javac MyClass.java' to compile in the directory containing the source, and you can use 'java MyClass'  to execute it in that directory.