# Error: Could not find or load main class (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, file, class, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Using the ls commmand, I can clearly see both the .java file and the .class file of my main class created from compilation. However, when I try to run it, the Ubuntu terminal says that the class was not found. Here's a screenshot of my terminal

[image]

And here's a snippet of my main class
[image]

Any answers?

Comment: try to execute it with `java -cp .. cs3242_emul/cs3242`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

Answer (score 0):

You haved a class inside package. So you should run your class in /home/se folder and use command java cs3421_emul.cs3421_emul

Answer (score 0):

Since your classes are in a package your compiled classes should in the proper folder structure.

To compile the classes to proper package folders use `-d .` switch while compiling.

```
javac -d . *.java
```

The above command will create folders based on the package of the classes. for example you `class3421_emul` has a package `class3421_emul` so it will be compiled to `class3421_emul` folder.

Then run the class using `java class3421_emul.class3421_emul`