# Could not find or load main a class in Java

Tags: java, classpath

i have the following project structure:

```
JavaTest
    Main
        Main.java
    Test
        Test.java
```

Main.java:

```
package Main;
import Test.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
package Test;
public class Test {
}
```

I compile them with the following commands:

```
D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest>javac Main\Main.java

D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest>javac Test\Test.java
```

The class files are put like this:

```
JavaTest
    Main
        Main.java
        Main.class
    Test
        Test.java
        Test.class
```

I'm trying to run it with the following command:

```
D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest>java -cp D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest\Main;D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest\Test Main
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the package to your main class and set the classpath to the base directory

```
D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest>java -cp D:\Development\Workspace\JavaTest Main.Main
```

I'd recommend you stick to Java conventions and use only lowercase names in your package.
And you don't need the Test path to run your class

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
javac -d . Main/Main.java
java Main.Main
```

**Notes:**

1. The current directory is represented by a `.`
2. I recommend you follow the Java naming convention. As per the naming convention, the name of your package should be `main`. Check https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html for more details.
3. Use the command, `javac -help` to know more about the options available with `javac`.