# Problem with running my java project from the command line (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, security, cybersource

I am currently working on a university project involving police patrol management. It is necessary to implement different security elements in order to keep the data protected. I have therefore designed a beginning of a Client Server application.

All works well when running on IntelliJ but things get complicated once in command line. The compilation works but the execution is impossible because of a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Here is my Project Structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eaMI.png)

Here is the error after trying to run only the Server side of the project :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptULZ.png)

Is this error due to the fact that I am using files with secret keys and a certificate ? Or is it just my structure that is causing the problem ?

Can you help me ?

Comment: Why would you need to run your app through the command line?

Comment: Because our teacher ask for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think every thing is ok except one thing..pay attention at ServerSide/Server

look at the second image you have sent ..
I had same problem . Look at this answer [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

You need to run it from the package root on. Go one folder up so that you're in the folder which in turn contains the "ServerSide" folder representing the package and then execute " java ServerSide .Server"

Comment: The file is well with a capital

Comment: give me feedback please . @Adrien Defer